# Sum of 2d array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I created a 2d object array called that stores a String country and a double array. I'm having trouble implementing a function to retrieve the sum of cellular stats of a country through a certain period. Basically if year is less than 1983(since the beginning year from data starts at 1983) it should return -1 cause it's out of bounds. The function trying to implement is called

```
getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(String country, int startYear, int endYear)
```

It takes the the country which you intend to print out the stats, the start of the year and end of year. Then you add the sum of the selected time period by getting the index difference of the year but i am having trouble implementing it. So for example if i pass ("USA", 1983, 1989) it should print the sum of total stats between 1983 and 1989. Display should be :usa (1983 to 1989): 3.14. I ran into trouble when trying to access the values in object and could not convert/cast into an object. Please suggestion will help.

```
public class CellularData {

private Object [][]array;

public CellularData(int rows, int columns, int year)
{
    array = new Object[rows+1][columns+1];
    array[0][0] = "Country";
    this.year = year;
    for(int i=1;i<=columns;i++)
    {
    array[0][i] = year++;
    }
}

public void addCountry(String country, double []num)
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {    
    if(array[i][0] == null)
    {
        addCountry(country, num, i);
        break;
    }
    }
}
private void addCountry(String country, double []num, int row)
{
    array[row][0] = country;
    for(int j = 1;j<array[row].length;j++)
    {
        array[row][j] = num[j-1];
    }
}
public double getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(String country, int sYear, int eYear)
{//trouble implementing the function
    double sum = 0;
    int indexStart = (int)(sYear - ((Integer) array[0][1]).doubleValue());

    for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i][0]==country && ((sYear<year)||(eYear>year)))
        {
            //System.out.print(array[i][0]);

        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public String toString()
{
    for(Object []a: array)
    {
        for(Object k:a)
        {
            System.out.print(k + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return " ";
}
}

 public class TestCellularData {

public static void main(String []args)
{
    final double[] usaPartial = {0,0,0.14,.28,.5,.83,1.39};
    final double[] canadaPartial = {0,0,.05,.23,.37,.75,1.26};
    final double[] mexicoPartial = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01};

     int numRows = 3;
     int numColumns = canadaPartial.length;
     int startingYear = 1983;

    CellularData datatable = new CellularData(numRows, numColumns, startingYear);
    datatable.addCountry("USA", usaPartial);
    datatable.addCountry("Mexico", mexicoPartial);
    datatable.addCountry("Canada", canadaPartial);

    System.out.println(datatable);

    System.out.printf("usa (1983 to 1989): %.2f \n",     datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("usa",1983,1989));
    // country is "usa", subscriptions from 1983 to 1989
    // the output is: 
    // usa (1983 to 1989): 3.14
    System.out.printf("mexico (1983 to 1989): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("mexico",1983,1989));
    // country is "mexico", subscriptions from 1983 to 1986
    // the output is:
    // mexico (1983 to 1989): 0.01                  
    // NOTE: in order to get this result, you must test beyond the sample data included here and refer to the CSV file.
    System.out.printf("canada (1890 to 2000): %.2f \n", datatable.getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod("canada",1890, 2000));
    // the output is:
    // ERROR : requested year 1890  is less than starting year 1893
    // canada (1890 to 2000): -1.00 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add number of countries you have in array:

```
public class CellularData {

    private Object[][] array;
    private final int year;
    private int countryNum = 0;  // number of countries in array

    public CellularData(int rows, int columns, int year) {
        array = new Object[rows + 1][columns + 1];
        array[0][0] = "Country";
        this.year = year;
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            array[0][i] = year++;
        }
        countryNum = 1;
    }
```

Now you can change your addCountry method to:

```
public void addCountry(String country, double[] num) {
    addCountry(country, num, countryNum++);
}
```

Next, in `getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod` method you have to compare strings in java way. Not by `==` opeator but by `equals()` method. You are using "USA" in array and "usa" in your test, so you needs ignore-case comparing: `equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
if ( country.equalsIgnoreCase((String)array[i][0])) {
```

Next you can modify you method to:

```
public double getNumSubscriptionsInCountryForPeriod(String country, int sYear, int eYear) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (country.equalsIgnoreCase((String) array[i][0])) {
            int start = 1 + sYear - year;
            int end = start + (eYear - sYear);

            if (start >= 0 && end < array[i].length) {

                for (int k = start; k <= end; k++) {
                    // System.out.println(">> " + country + " adding " + array[i][k]);
                    sum += (Double) array[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```